# If I entered wrong password then it will just take me to the next route without saving user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm creating dummy Netflix site but in the signup page I want to save user which is not in the database and if user is present in the database then just go to the next route.
But if entered email and entered password will not match then I just want to show error-text.
But if I entered wrong password then it will just take me to the next route without saving user.
I just don't get it what's happening there.
This is my app.js signup route

```
app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
   Netflix.find({}, function (err, user) {
       res.render("Signup", { email: app.get('data'), Users: user });
   });

});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
   const User = new Netflix({
       email: app.get('data'),
       password: req.body.password
   });
   Netflix.findOne({ "email": app.get('data') }, { "password": req.body.password }, function (err, user) {
       if(user){
           res.redirect("/Netflix/Movies");
       }
       else{
           User.save((err)=>{
               if(err){
                   res.send(err);
               }
               else{
                   res.redirect("/Netflix/Movies");
               }
           });
           
       }

   });
});
```

This is signup.ejs file.

```
  <body>

        <section class="section">
            <div class="container3">
                <header>
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="/image/Netflix_Logo_RGB.png" alt="Netflix logo"></img>
                    </div>
                    <a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
                    <div class="hr"></div>
                </header>
                <div id="error-text">
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
                    <p> <span>Incorrect password.</span>
                        Please try again or you can reset your password.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="containt">
                    <h3>
                        Welcome back, <%- email.substring(0, email.indexOf('@')); %>!<br>
                            Rejoining Netflix is easy.
                    </h3>
                    <p>Enter your password and you'll be watching in no time.<br></p>
                    <p class="main">
                        Email<br>
                        <span>
                           <%= email %>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <form class="continue" action="/signup" method="POST">
                        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" name="password">
                        <p class="forgot">Forgot your password?</p>
                        <button onclick="check()">Continue</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function check(){
                let Users = <%- JSON.stringify(Users) %>;
                console.log("hello");
                Users.forEach(element => {
                    var enteredEmail = <%- JSON.stringify(email) %>;
                    var enteredPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
                    if(element.email === enteredEmail && element.password === enteredPassword){
                        document.getElementById("error-text").style.display = "none";
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("error-text").style.display = "block";
                        document.getElementsByClassName("containt").style.top = "270";
                    }
                });
            }



        </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(user){
           res.redirect("/Netflix/Movies");
       }
       else{
           User.save((err)=>{
               if(err){
                   res.send(err);
               }
               else{
                   res.redirect("/Netflix/Movies");
               }
           });
           
       }
```

You're redirecting to `/Netflix/Movies/` if there isn't a user with matching credentials. Try redirecting to another 404 or "invalid credentials" url path.

Answer (score 0):

your findOne is not rightly implemented(findone takes one object as a parameter)  due to which you are getting user as `{}`
which is an empty object and is a truthy value

also you might wanna write `findOne` like this

`Netflix.findOne({ "email": app.get('data'),  "password": req.body.password }, function (err, user) {`